# How do I change the default sending email address permanently?

Tags: thunderbird

I am having trouble changing the default sending email address. I have 5 email accounts in Thunderbird.

I can change the default sending address by going to Tools->Account Settings->Account Actions->Set as Default. This work fine as long as Thunderbird remains open. However, if I close and reopen Thunderbird the default sending address switches back to the wrong one.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Even though you have mentioned this, check again that the settings are saved:

> click OK to save the settings - re-open the account settings dialog
>   --> the selected account is not underlined anymore. [Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1251748)
>
> You can change which account is set as default.
>
> - 'Tools' > 'Account Settings'
> - select the mail account you want to set up as default
> - click on 'Account actions'
> - select: 'Set as Default'
> - click on OK to save changes.
>
> The info 'Tools' > 'Account Settings' assumes you have enabled all
>   your toolbars. Otherwise you can also access 'Account settings' via:
>
> - '3bar menu icon' > 'Options' > 'Account Settings'
>
> or
>
> - right click on mail account in left Folder Pane and select 'Settings'.
>
> As you only have two mail accounts, it is easy to swap the default and
>   change the order they are displayed.  If you later add several mail
>   accounts and need to change the order of those accounts, not just set
>   a default, you can use this addon:
>
> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/manually-sort-folders/
>
> Please note that this addon also allows you to rearrange folders. [Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/996194)

2. Otherwise I would suggesting trying in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/safe-mode-thunderbird) (with addons disabled).
3. Review Thunderbird Profile Information [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird) and [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_-_Thunderbird) for a detailed understanding of the profile settings. It is likely that this setting is stored in the [Prefs.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js) which (backup first) can be directly edited with a text editor.
4. Try a fresh install and copy the profile across.

Further Reading

- [How to change default sender address in address book](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1183262)
- [Moving Thunderbird Data to a New Computer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer)

Comment: Thank you. Starting in safe mode changed the order of my addresses such that the new default address is now first in the list and remained as the default. This has continued to be the case when restarting without safe mode.